# Using php preg_match to get an id from forum quotes

Tags: php, forum, quote

I've been using `preg_match` to try and get an id from a quote in my forums I have written. This is what I have so far.

```
$quote = '[quote]19[\quote] This is a reply to the quote.';

$get = '/([quote])([0-9])([\quote])/';

$id = '';

preg_match($get, $quote, $id);

echo $id[0];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give me the result I was hoping for and I have tried many variations and even tried `preg_replace` in hopes that might give me what I need but After a lot of reading on stack overflow I think `preg_match` is the way to go. I just can't seem to get what I want which is the id in between the quote tags.

My experience with `preg` is limited at best and I've tried my best to try to get it to work but unfortunately it is beyond my current knowledge so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Escape the brackets \\[  \\] as they have a special meaning, character class definition, in Regex. And remove the braces (...) around [quote] and [/quote]. The result would bei in $id[1], i guess.

Comment: `[0-9]` matches 1 number, you are probably looking for something like `[0-9]+` which will match1 or more numbers

Comment: I tried this before and just tried it again and I'm getting undefined offset 0 & 1.

Comment: Thanks kingkero I did wonder why in my previous attempts I got a 1 or a 9 but never both.

Comment: Sorry, the offset error was due to me echoing $id[0] and $id[1] to see if it worked unfortunately it hasn't returned any results.

Comment: I added a commented answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hints

- **[** and **]** are used as character class delimiters.
  They must be escaped \[, \] when to be taken literally.
  The definition [0-9] means exactly this: the character class of digits.
- **(…)** brackets embrace the result group.
  If you wish to extract the numeric data between [quote] and [\quote] only ([0-9]*?) should be in brackets. The result would then be in $id[1] (group # 1).
- The **backslash "\"** character in [\quote] must be escaped too, as it is the escape character itself: [\\\\quote] (4 times \, since it is interpreted twice; somehow tricky, I know).
  Btw: maybe [/quote] is meant; that would make it easier (?)

### Code

```
<?php
    $quote1 = '[quote]19[\quote] This is a reply to the quote.';
    $quote2 = '[quote]19[/quote] This is a reply to the quote.';
    // $get = '/\[quote\]([0-9].*?)\[\quote\]/';
    $get1 = '%\[quote\]([0-9]*?)\[\\\\quote\]%';
    $get2 = '%\[quote\]([0-9]*?)\[/quote\]%';
    $id = '';
    preg_match($get1, $quote1, $id);
    echo '$get1,$quote1 :: ' . $id[1] . '<br />';
    preg_match($get2, $quote2, $id);
    echo '$get2,$quote2 :: ' . $id[1] . '<br />';
?>
```

Output:
$get1,$quote1 :: 19
$get2,$quote2 :: 19

### Regex commented

```
    \[          # Match the character “[” literally
    quote       # Match the characters “quote” literally
    \]          # Match the character “]” literally
    (           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
       [0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
          *?          # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    )
    \[          # Match the character “[” literally
        \\\\       # Match the character “\” literally
    quote       # Match the characters “quote” literally
    \]          # Match the character “]” literally
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, unfortunately this isn't returning any results for me. I have typed out the code exactly as you put it so I'm going to change the \ in the last quote tag and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ok so I changed the slash in the last tag and it still is not returning any results. This is what I currently have: $get = '%\[quote\]([0-9]*?)\[/quote\]%';

Comment: Hmm - I've tested the code before submitting, and it produced the right result (19). To be sure, I just made an edit and posted it again, right from my test script. So, please try again. Maybe you copy and paste it.

Comment: Oh I see: maybe this interface cuts out the \ characters in front of [ and ] characters in your comment. Otherwise you have forgotten them - they are important. And no, for sure it's not the \ in the last quote.

Comment: I finally got it to work, thank you very much for your time and help on this, I really appreciate it.